# Shell script to delete certain text from all index.php files on the server

Tags: shell, text

It seems like some malicious script have found it's way onto the server where I hold my webpages. I have several accounts and they are all "infected" (not sure if this is the right word).

Anyway. All index.php files have been prepended with the following code:

```
<marquee style="position: absolute; width: 0px;">
<a href="http://istanbulescort-ilan.com/" title="escort bayan">escort bayan</a>
<a href="http://istanbulescort-ilan.com/" title="bayan escort">bayan escort</a>
<a href="http://ankaraescortlari.org/" title="ankara escort">ankara escort</a>
<a href="http://ankaraescortlari.org/" title="ankara escort bayan">ankara escort bayan</a>
<a href="http://ankaraescortlari.org/" title="escort ankara">escort ankara</a>
...
<a href="http://hurhaberci.com" title="son haberler">son haberler</a>
</marquee>
```

This code messes up headers and web pages don't render well. Not to mention I have some escort services links on all of my webpages.

I've found this script, but I'm not sure how to correctly modify it to remove all of the above code from all index.php files on each of accounts on the server. I don't want to run it and then find out I have to restore hudge backup.

```
for i in /directory/*.java
do
   # echo 'Working on $i file'
   copy $i tempfil.txt
   sed   -e '/\} catch/,/^\}/d' tempfil.txt > $i
done
```

[EDIT]

Ok, so I managed to scrape this together. Can someone please just confirm it will work or give any suggestions about what should be changed?

```
read -d '' hacked <<"EOF"
<marquee style="position: absolute; width: 0px;">
<a href="http://istanbulescort-ilan.com/" title="escort bayan">escort bayan</a>
...
<a href="http://gidasayfasi.com" title="gida">gida</a></marquee>
EOF
find -name \*.php | xargs replace ${hacked} ""  --
```

Comment: By the way, I use centos with cpanel if this helps with folder structure.

Comment: Restore those files from a backup. You can't assume there are no other changes. If you don't have a backup, you should manually inspect all those files for malicious code.

Comment: I have same structure on all of my websites (I'm using joomla) and I have already inspected thoroughly all files that might contain something malicious. Problem is I have weekly backups and all websites are very active. Next backup is tomorrow and I have already pulled down this week old files, but restoring them will destroy all content that was accumulated until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete prepended text (assuming there is not something useful inside the prepended text):

```
sed '/<marquee/,/marquee>/ d' index.php
```

`/EXP1/, /EXP2/ d` means that sed matches lines between expression EXP1 and expression EXP2, then apply action 'd' (which is 'delete').

Hope this helps.

---- edit according to the comment below ---
---- there may be correct code inside the malicious one ----
You can imagine to copy/paste the portion of text to delete in a text file name 'tobedeleted.txt'. Then write the following script process.sh (where $1 is the file to clean up)

```
#/bin/bash
diff --suppress-common-lines $1 tobedeleted.txt | grep -e '^<' | sed 's/^< //'
```

the diff command above show you only the difference between the reference malicious code and the content of file $1. The difference is computed line by line and shows a markup character '< ' before the line (see `man diff`).
Please try this command first.

You can call the script (do a `chmod u+x process.sh` first to make it executable) and redirect the result into another script, for example:

```
process.sh index.php > new_index.php
```

So, to correct a large number of files, do a script like:

```
#/bin/bash
find . -name "*.php" | while read pathfile
do
   file=${pathfile##*/} # remove the path from the fullpath to the file
   pathonly=${pathfile%/*} # keep only the path
   cp $pathfile ${pathonly}/${file}.org # copy original file to save it, in case of...
   process.sh  ${pathonly}/${file}.org > ${pathfile} # apply correction
done
```

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more detailed. I came up with this after some more research. (because I don't want remove any "innocent" content that can be found within marquee tags)


`read -d '' hacked <<"EOF"
<marquee style="position: absolute; width: 0px;">
<a href="http://istanbulescort-ilan.com/" title="escort bayan">escort bayan</a>
...
<a href="http://gidasayfasi.com" title="gida">gida</a></marquee>
EOF
find -name \*.php | xargs replace ${hacked} ""  --`

Can someone please check this to see if it's correct? Because I'm really no expert at writing shell scripts.

Comment: @Jinx: I tried to propose a solution so that correct code inside the malicious one would no prevent to strip out the malicious one. It is based on the difference detection between a reference copy of the malicious one and the php file. Please run it on a test file (a copy of an infected file), and if you run it, save a copy of the infected files (as I did in the while loop attached to the find command).